# Should I never call HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

While trying to implement asyncronous email over smtp in my ASP.Net MVC 3 application I've come around [SO SmtpClient.SendAsync blocking my ASP.NET MVC Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935427/smtpclient-sendasync-blocking-my-asp-net-mvc-request) thread. There I found the article by Phil Haack: [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) which provides a way to avoid crashing of the background thread on AppDomain shutdown.

The article says to call `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);` on the constructor and call `HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);` only if [IRegisteredObject.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject.stop.aspx) is called.

In a general scenario, when requests arrive permanently, and the scope of the object implementing `IRegisteredObject` is request, dosn't this approach register objects within each request (utilizing the email functionality) and does not unregister any?

Is it OK? Or should I also unregister after the asynchronous operation completed?

P.S.: as suggested by Damian Edwards in the linked SO question, I use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to send the email beyond request scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `requests arrive permanently`, `scope of the object ... is request` etc.

`Request Scope`, `permanent`, and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`; these words together do not make sense at all. One uses `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` so that a request does not take forever. The time-consuming job is done in the background while your request returns immediately as Damian Edwards suggests.

I have used `IRegisterObject` to send bulk e-mails upon a request received. However, in my case, I have used a singleton object `EmailSender` that implements `IRegisterObject`. In that case, it is registered once in the constructor and unregistered once in `Stop()`.

So, in short, please use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).